# Django formset hidden id field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset and when I render it, Django would include this line in the HTML:

```
<input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden">
```

I am curious what is the purpose of having an id field here. (My model doesn't have an predefined id field, and I am sure this id field is not the primary key id field of my model)

I mean in what situation would you use it. I did look through Django's [documentation on formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete) but cannot find much documentation on this.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you sure that "this id field is not the primary id field of my model"? That is exactly what it is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I wrote `exclude=['id']` to try to exclude it and it still showed up. Also, I would like to know why the downvote

Comment: But that would do nothing. Model formsets *always* need the ID, and explicitly add it back in if it is not present; otherwise how would they know which form's data to save to which row in the database?

Comment: @DanielRoseman your argument makes sense. Also, I didn't know exclude doesn't work on pk due to lack of documentation. But is it wise to leave the pk exposed like this. Because it leaves the opportunity of being tempered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ids are used to know whether the object have to be updated or created (no id).

The id simply tells what object have to be updated/deleted if applicable.

I can't find the reference of what I'm saying right now, but I'll put it here when I find.

Comment: Thanks and looking forward to see the reference. When I append a new form into the set via javascript, I have to generate all of the field names myself and I can generate this id too if it is important. It would be a bad indicator for updated or created in my opinion. Anyways, I am just curious why django inserted the line.